# How to store hobbies as an array for the below javascript code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, javascript-objects

I want to create a form which form which takes input from the form and on submit prints it on the console as an javascript object. I can print all the fields except the hobbies part where the object takes only one checked value and doesn't take the rest checked one's. Would be glad if someone could help me or link me a similar problem that is solved already.

[image]

this is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './contact.css';
import { json } from 'react-router-dom';
function Contact() {





    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({});

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('hobby');
        var hobbies = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            if (checkboxes[i].checked == true) {
                hobbies.push(checkboxes[i].value);
            }
        }
        console.log(hobbies);
        const name = event.target.name;
        const value = event.target.value;
        setInputs(values => ({ ...values, [name]: value }))
    }

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        /* if (inputs != "") {
             console.log(inputs);
             const myJSON = JSON.stringify(inputs);
             // console.log(myJSON);
             setInputs("");
         }*/
        /*var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('hobby');
        var hobbies = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            if (checkboxes[i].checked == true) {
                hobbies.push(checkboxes[i].value);
            }
        }
        console.log(hobbies);
*/



    }


    return <address>

        <form className='container' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="form-row" >
                <label >Firstname:</label>
                <div className="col mt-2">
                    <input type="text" id='firstname' name="firstname" value={inputs.firstname || ""} onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" placeholder="First name"></input>
                </div>
                <div className="form-row">
                    <div className="col mt-2">
                        <label >Lastname:</label>
                        <input type="text" id='lastname' name="lastname" value={inputs.lastname || ""} onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" placeholder="Last name"></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-row">
                    <div className="col mt-2">
                        <label >Age:</label>
                        <input type="number" id='age' name="age" value={inputs.age || ""} onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" placeholder="Age"></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col mt-2">
                    <label >Height:</label>
                    <input type="number" step="any" id='height' name="height" value={inputs.height || ""} onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" placeholder="Height"></input>
                </div>
                <div className="col mt-2">
                    <label >Gender:</label>
                    <input type="text" maxLength='1' name="gender" value={inputs.gender || ""} onChange={handleChange} id='gender' className="form-control" placeholder="Gender"></input>
                </div>
                <div className="col mt-2">
                    <label >Hobbies:</label>
                    <div className="form-check">
                        <input className="form-check-input" name="hobby" id='hobbies' type="checkbox" value='cricket' onChange={handleChange} ></input>
                        <label className="form-check-label">
                            Cricket
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-check">
                        <input className="form-check-input" name="hobby" id='hobbies' type="checkbox" value='football' onChange={handleChange} ></input>
                        <label className="form-check-label">
                            Football
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-check">
                        <input className="form-check-input" name="hobby" id='hobbies' type="checkbox" value='reading' onChange={handleChange}></input>
                        <label className="form-check-label">
                            Reading
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-check">
                        <input className="form-check-input" name="hobby" id='hobbies' type="checkbox" value='Dancing' onChange={handleChange} ></input>
                        <label className="form-check-label">
                            Dancing
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className='col mt-2'>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" id='jsonbtn'>Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <p id='demo'></p>
    </address>

}

export default Contact;
```

Answer (score 0):

please change as below

and in html for `checkbox` use `handleCheckbox`

```
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        const name = event.target.name;
        const value = event.target.value;
        setInputs(values => ({ ...values, [name]: value }))
    }

    const handleCheckbox = (event) => {
        let hobby = values.hobby || [];

        const value = event.target.value;
        const checked = event.target.checked;

        if (checked) hobby = [...hobby, value];
        else hobby = hobby.filter(item => item !== value);

        setInputs(values => ({ ...values, hobby }))
    }
```

Comment: I changed the onchange function of checkboxes to handlecheckbox. I got an error saying values in values.hobby is not definded. so I changed it to value.hobby but now whenever I click on the checkboxes I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'value' before initialization".

Comment: @joelnoronha please update in handleCheckbox `let hobby = values && values.hobby ? values.hobby : [];
 `